# Need help applying this JavaScript code to my existing code

Tags: javascript, html

I've very nearly finished a simple music toggle button I've been working on and wanted it to fade into my page like the scroll to top button does on my website ([like the one which you can see here when scrolling down](http://www.scrolltotop.com/)).

I managed to get the javascript from the scroll to top button which looks as follows:

```
var start = {
  setting: {
    startline: 100,
    scrollto: 0,
    scrollduration: 1e3,
    fadeduration: [500, 100]
  },
  controlHTML: '<img src=".../noaudio.png"/>',
  },
  state: {
    isvisible: !1,
    shouldvisible: !1
  },
  scrollup: function() {
  this.cssfixedsupport || this.$control.css({
  opacity: 0
    });
    var t = isNaN(this.setting.scrollto) ? this.setting.scrollto : parseInt(this.setting.scrollto);
    t = "string" == typeof t && 1 == jQuery("#" + t).length ? jQuery("#" + t).offset().top : 0, this.$body.animate({
      scrollTop: t
    }, this.setting.scrollduration)
  },
  keepfixed: function() {
     var t = jQuery(window),
      o = t.scrollLeft() + t.width() - this.$control.width() - this.controlattrs.offsetx,
      s = t.scrollTop() + t.height() - this.$control.height() - this.controlattrs.offsety;
    this.$control.css({
      left: o + "px",
      top: s + "px"
    })
  },
  togglecontrol: function() {
     var t = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    this.cssfixedsupport || this.keepfixed(), this.state.shouldvisible = t >= this.setting.startline ? !0 : !1, this.state.shouldvisible && !this.state.isvisible ? (this.$control.stop().animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, this.setting.fadeduration[0]), this.state.isvisible = !0) : 0 == this.state.shouldvisible && this.state.isvisible && (this.$control.stop().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, this.setting.fadeduration[1]), this.state.isvisible = !1)
  },
  init: function() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(t) {
```

I had a go at changing it to work for the new button I added but had no luck so far. [Here's what I've got so far.][2]

So, how can I make the new button fade in like the one on my website? Is there a way to do it with the code I linked above?

Thanks

Also, sorry for any errors. I still suck at coding.

Comment: Where is the rest of `init`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/71uncr2g/8/

Try that. I was working on something like this right now. This is the jQuery code:

```
var amountScrolled = 300;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolled ) {
        $('.fadebutton').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('.fadebutton').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```